# How can i reach object inside array, mylist = [{whole: 'thing', code: 'a'}, {whole: 'thing2', code: 'b'}]

Tags: javascript

I can only get the whole array of objects cant reach inside objects

```
list = [{whole: 'thing', code: 'a'}, {whole: 'things', code: 'b'}]
```

console.log(list) gives me the list as object with key value pairs in it. But I need to reach the value of whole and code

Comment: just need this `list[index].whole`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It sounds like you need to learn more about how to access/manipulate data in javascript. Free Code Camp is an excellent resource for that

Comment: you know I could've asked this a bit better the problem was a bit more complicated i found it and i wont share here why do people give - to my questions? fuck this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let list = [
  { whole: 'thing', code: 'a' },
  { whole: 'things', code: 'b'},
];

// access specific whole of object at index

console.log(list[0].whole);
console.log(list[1].whole);

// print each whole of object in list

list.forEach(({ whole }) => console.log(whole));
```